# Convert Data Frame into a json file

Tags: python, json, pandas

[ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EgXaA.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOjhk.png)I have a dataframe which has been encoded with pd.dummies. 
I want to make a JSON file of it.

I have converted it into json by the below code however I want the headers too.

```
export_file = dropped.to_json (r'file_path.json', orient='records')
```

Expected:

```
{"headers": [ "married","never married","divorced","seperated","unknown"], "data":["10000","01000","00100","00010","00001"]}
```

Actual:

```
"SEPARATED":0,"UNKNOWN":0,"WIDOWED":0},{"DIVORCED":0,"MARRIED":0,"NEVER MARRIED":0,"SEPARATED":0,"UNKNOWN":0,"WIDOWED":1},{"DIVORCED":0,"MARRIED":0,"NEVER MARRIED":0,"SEPARATED":0,"UNKNOWN":1,"WIDOWED":0},{"DIVORCED":0,"MARRIED":0,"NEVER MARRIED":0,"SEPARATED":1,"UNKNOWN":0,"WIDOWED":0}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
#sample  data
a = ["married|divorced|unknown","never married|married","divorced","seperated|unknown"]
df = pd.Series(a).str.get_dummies()
print (df)
   divorced  married  never married  seperated  unknown
0         1        1              0          0        1
1         0        1              1          0        0
2         1        0              0          0        0
3         0        0              0          1        1
```

Create `dictionary` manually, data join in list comprehension and then convert to `json`:

```
d = {"headers": df.columns.tolist(), 'data':[''.join(x) for x in df.values.T.astype(str)]}
print (d)
{'headers': ['divorced', 'married', 'never married', 'seperated', 'unknown'], 
 'data': ['1010', '1100', '0100', '0001', '1001']}

j = json.dumps(d)
print (j)
{"headers": ["divorced", "married", "never married", "seperated", "unknown"], 
 "data": ["1010", "1100", "0100", "0001", "1001"]}
```

---

```
import json
with open('data.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(d, outfile)
```

Comment: This works! thank you so much! How do i write this into a text file ?

Comment: @tiredcoder - check last paragraph, need changhe `.txt` file change `'data.json'` to `'data.txt'`

Comment: @tiredcoder - Can you explain more, what is problem? Some error?

Comment: I have attached the ERROR image. Please check it out. Also, it shows the same error in other dataframes as well!

Comment: @tiredcoder = If check my answer carefully, in `data` are created `01` values like `"data": ["1010", "1100", "0100", "0001", "1001"]}` - it means for each column are separate joined data. so for first column are `1010`, for second `1100` and similar. do you need something else?

Comment: The encoded_data has only zeros, there is no "1" anywhere.

Comment: one_hot_three = pd.get_dummies(data['NATUREOFAPPOINTMENTDESCRIPTION'])
data_three = data_three.drop('NATUREOFAPPOINTMENTDESCRIPTION', axis=1)
data_three = data_three.join(one_hot_three)

Comment: @tiredcoder - hmmm, if check `one_hot_three` there has to be at least one `1` in column. Is possible check it? But there is most `0` values. So if convert it to json, same thing - maybe few 1, all another are 0. So if not check very carefully, it seems only 0.

Comment: No it does have 1. I will figure it out. thank you.

Comment: Hello, I was doing a little mistake. Your code works fine for all data frames.